# How to delete all records that has incorrect binary type value

Tags: mysql

Normally I would have tried something but I do not know where to start. I have inherited an old project where the database is somewhat damaged. When using Laravel to make a `Like` query, I got back:

> [] Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Using SQLPro with the exact query:

```sql
select * from TABEL where UPPER(Name) LIKE '%QUOTE%' AND COLUMN_NAME = 3;
```

I got back a `uuid` column of type `BINARY` and its values are `¢çýiPäEÀ Vüqÿã`, `HpWãÐ@¿«¡À´Þ ©` etc

Column `uuid` is the issue as I see way older devs where inserting test data and left it there. Is there a way to remove all those "strange characters" records that reads in english:

- Delete ALL FROM TABLE WHERE UUID HAS malformat BIRANY?

There is noting unique about these records where I could easily do

```sql
DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE Column = 'foo';
```

Comment: binary types contain binary datas, not necessary readable strings

Comment: Some of the results I got back: `uuid: adfb8e18-5da0-11`

Comment: Maybe they all have spaces? You can look for an special chr too, or if the uuid have same lenghts between dashes, look for that

Comment: @Alejandro It seems that way. I'll see what I can do with the ones with spaces.